# How do I fix an error about unclean file system NTFS when mounting?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have install Ubuntu 13.04 along side with Window8 the first time I can use it very well but after few time I restart my machine and I try to use the file from another HDD(I have 2 HDD 1 is 160GB which I install the OS on it.2 is 1000GB what I have in it just the photo file,video,movie and song).now when I start up my machine and I try to view file in my 2 HDD what I have is this message...
I want to show a picture but I can not the picture of my error is here..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't really related to Ubuntu as it is a Microsoft design decision. However, what you need to do, is configure Windows 8 to do proper shutdown instead of hibernating. The same thing can happen if you have NTFS on a USB memory stick and pull it out without unmounting it first.

It is *possible* that you can use `ntfsfix -d`, but it is also possible that this might harm your Windows install, so you need to take precautions if you want to try it.